# Is liquid layout good or creating multiple css file for universal accessibility of web pages?

Tags: html, css, website-design

Is liquid layout (everything in % and font-size in 'em') good or creating multiple css file for different resolutions or browsers with help of Javascript good?

I am a aspiring web designer, and want create a universal accessible web pages?

Answer (score 5):

The trend is moving towards 'responsive web design' rather than liquid layouts measured in percentages.

CSS3 introduced [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), which allow you to serve different styles depending on device resolution, without needing to resort to Javascript, so this makes it far more flexible when designing for multiple devices.

[Ethan Marcotte](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/) is the person who popularised the term responsive web design - in fact, he basically [wrote the book on it](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). His article on A List Apart is a good place to get started:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

For some inspiration on what can be achieved with media queries and responsive web design, check out http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: Unfortunetly CSS3 media queries are not supported in Internet Explorer prior to version 9 so I would hold of using them just yet. http://caniuse.com/#search=media

Comment: Well, my answer is meant to support best practices for 'aspiring web designers'. Support for media queries can be enabled for older versions of IE using a framework like '320 and Up': http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/320_and_up